# Не отображаются картинки после переноса сайта на локальный сервер

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, openserver, изображения

Перенес сайт на `wordpress` с постоянного места хранилища на локальный сервер под руководством `open server` (положил в папку **domains**), все настроил, пути прописал, но большинство картинок (лого, в записях и т.д.) на нем не подтягивается - в коде отображаются в таком виде:

```
<a href="http://site.ru/category/article/" style="background-image: url('site.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/12/12.jpg')">...</a>
```

Но, если на картинку навести или перейти, то переход осуществляется по такому адресу

`http://site.ru/site.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/12/12.jpg`

Где искать проблему и как ее устранить?

Comment: Похоже, неправильно перенесли. Надо плагином duplicator

Comment: @KAGG Design, спасибо, а как можно исправить? Сайт огромный - повторно переносить и настраивать времени и возможности нет..

Comment: Если все работает кроме картинок значит косяк в БД при заливке, проверьте еще раз пути в файлике базы и перезалейте. Возможно на картинках прописан абсолютный путь

Comment: файлы уже перенесли - хорошо. Теперь повторно только базу, а это совсем недолго. Но именно с помощью duplicator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос! Расскажу как:

1. тут немножко сам заложал - изменил пути на локалке без `http://`
   добавил и часть картинок подтянулась
2. для локальных тестов у меня был отключен иннет - включил
3. теперь в начале путей http://i1.wp.com/ стала прописываться - это начудил Photon модуль плагина Jetpack (таким образом он налету картинки якобы сжимает и оптимизирует), зашел в настройки Jetpack / Settings (site.cru/wp-admin/admin.php?page=jetpack_modules) и деактивировал Photon модуль.
4. Заработало!